# 555 timer with 12 V LED pulsing

Tags: 555, led-strip, 12v

I have been making a pulsing LED circuit and I have a 12 V LED strip and a 12v supply. I need bright LEDs for my project but the issue is that my 12 V LEDs don't work because the base of Transistor 1 from the 555 timer is around 4-8 V and I need it to be around 10-12 V in order for the LED strip to work.

Below is my circuit, it's a combination of 555 pulsing and an inverted light sensor. Power supply is 12V and 5A

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPpgay.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Have you measured the voltage as 1-5V? The base of T1 should be ramp between 4 and 8V

Comment: What is the resistance range of R3? What is the voltage of P1? 12V? Then say so explicitly.

Comment: feed the 555 output to an n-chan mosfet's gate whose source is gnd and drain is the LED strip's -.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy P1 is potentiometer, R3 is a photocell. Yes its 12v.

Comment: @Mukira you're right, it's 4-8 volts which the goal is to be 10-12v. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @dandavis is there another way? I was thinking using transistor but don't know how. I don't have a mosfet

Comment: Welcome! Your schematic is hard to read. Please don't line up all components in a row and let your connections go haywire (some pun intended). Instead, please follow EE convention of inputs to the left, outputs to the right, positive voltages pointing up and ground and negative voltages down. Signal flow is from left to right. Feel free to name nodes so that you don't need wires all over the schematic.

Comment: According to your schematic, P1 is a battery, not a potentiometer. In any event, if the voltage is 12V, you should provide that information in your schematic. The symbol you use for R3 indicates that it is a photoresistor. What is NOT clear is what range of values it may take on. Do you have a part number?

Comment: just order some irlz44n's from ali or ebay, they are cheap and effective, even the knock-offs.

Comment: Connect the base of T1 to OUT of NE555, not to the R/C ramp

Comment: @Jens From what I understand OP is trying to make a pulsing/fade LED circuit. Connecting T1 to OUT is just going to switch the lights on or off.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy R3 is photoresistor I just called it photocell, photocells usually have 0 to 1M resistance (theoretically there's no resistance at light and infinite resistance at full dark)

Comment: @parpar8090 What LED strip are you using? Wattage specifically, without knowing how big the load is it's hard to give a solution